# Extjs combobox using jsonp

Tags: extjs, jsonp

Is it possible to configure an Extjs combobox where the remote queryMode utilises a jsonp request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes just make your store use a http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.JsonP

```
Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'name', 'email']
});

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'User',
    proxy: {
        type: 'jsonp',
        url : 'http://domainB.com/users'
    }
});


Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose User',
    store: store,
    queryMode: 'remote',
    displayField: 'email',
    valueField: 'id',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

The following script tag will be injected

```
<script src="http://domainB.com/users?callback=callback1"></script>
```

Comment: Juan, I am hosting a meetup in San Diego in a couple of weeks. Stop by http://www.meetup.com/SoCalSencha/  - Dmitry.

Comment: @dbrin I have given an Ext-JS talk at that same place, I'll try to make it.

Comment: Cool, Mats from Bryntum will be in SD and will present Siesta most likely.

Comment: This maybe out of scope here but could someone perhaps explain the script tag callback function. Why is not included in the javascript function